# Not able to access css and js from html in spring maven project

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring, maven

I have gone through most of the SO questions related to accessing css and js from a jsp page but have not found a solution. 
I am able to access my html page, css and js from the browser, so spring is able to map all my resources correctly but my html page is not accessing my css and js.

Here is my directory structure:

```
    src/main/webapp/static/css/app.css  
    src/main/webapp/static/js/fieldNamesCntrl.js  
    src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/docView.html
```

My servlet contains:

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
     <mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/views/" mapping="/views/**" />
      <mvc:resources location="/static/" mapping="/static/**" />
```

My web.xml contains:

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
     <servlet-name>auth</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>auth</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/auth/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

EDIT1 - Including my complete html header 
This is how I have included my css and js in html:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Page</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/app.css" type="text/css" /> 
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/static/js/fieldNamesCntrl.js"  type="text/javascript">
      </script>
```

Please suggest additional headers to be added to the html or if I can use pom for adding angularjs and bootstrap css.
Not sure what am I missing!

Comment: your screenshot isn't showing up

Answer (score 0):

I was able to debug this. The problem was the path for the css and js which I was giving in the html header. On deploying the application was looking for /static/css and /static/js in the same folder as .html, that is in the /static was getting appended in the /views folder.

The below code works:

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/app.css" type="text/css" />
     <script src="../static/js/fieldNamesCntrl.js"  type="text/javascript">
```

This makes sure that the right css and js folder is looked up. 
Thanks!